# How do I split delimited strings in a list when not all items are delimited in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, split, delimiter

I have a column of strings in a text file w/o a header (test_in.txt):

```
apple 
orange
banana
grape;pear;plum
cherry
pineapple
```

That I would like to have read:

```
apple
orange
banana
grape
pear
plum
cherry
pineapple
```

I'm using the following code:

```
with open("test_out.txt", "wt") as outfile:
with open("test_in.txt", "rt") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        line.split(";")
        outfile.write(line)
```

Can't seem to get it to work.  I've tried "if" statements as well, but I'm definitely missing something.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`line.split(";")` returns the different words of your line, it does not modify `line` in place, so you need to write each returned word:

```
for word in line.split(";"):
    outfile.write(word)
```

Alternatively, you just replace all `;` characters by `\n`, for instance with:

```
outfile.write(infile.read().replace(';', '\n'))
```

Comment: Hmm. When I try that, I get the same list, but without the semicolons.  Seems the "split" never happened.

Comment: Because you are relying on the end of line from the input. Try `outfile.write(word.rstrip()+'\n')` or `for word in line.rstrip().split(';'):`.

Comment: Your first suggestion of `outfile.write(word.rstrip()+'\n')` worked but not the second. The second resulted in one long concatenated string. Trying to figure out why. In any event, thank you greatly for the help!

Comment: Oh yeah, you still need the `+'\n'` for the second. It just reduces the number of stripping.

Comment: Oh man.  Your alternate solution was by far the easiest/simplest solution!  Didn't think at all to "replace" anything!  Thanks!